# Strange arrow mark with TikZ edge and anchors.

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I draw an edge between two nodes with anchors and globally set option `[->]`, I get an additional arrow tip symbol at the beginning of the last edge in the path. For example in

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
    \node (B) at (1,0) {$B$};

    \draw[->] (A.north east) edge (B.north west);

    \draw (A.south east) edge[->] (B.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the first `\draw` command produces incorrect output, while the second produces correct output:

[image: result]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in TikZ?

Comment: Nowadays, [`tips=proper` or `tips=on proper draw`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/tips) can be used so that PGF/TikZ will *not* draw that lonely arrow tip of that otherwise empty parent path. Though, using `\path` with `edge` is still the better solution to this problem – unless, of course, there is an actual path besides the `edge`s.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that you are using `\draw`, while `edge` is usually used in conjunction with `\path`.

What happens when you use the `edge` operation is that TikZ first draws everything up to the `edge` keyword, and then starts a new path with the `every edge` style between the nodes/coordinates specified in your `edge` operation. So using `edge` essentially splits your `\draw` command in two:

```
\draw[->] (A.north east) edge (B.north west);
```

is the same as saying

```
\draw[->] (A.north east);
\path[every edge,->] (A.north east) -- (B.north west);
```

The first line will just create the arrowhead pointing up, while the second line creates the actual line with the arrow head.

Your example can be corrected like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0) {$A$};
    \node (B) at (1,0) {$B$};

    \path[->] (A.north east) edge (B.north west);

    \draw (A.south east) edge[->] (B.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just ran into this. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `to` instead of `edge` like `\draw[->] (A.north east) to (B.north west);`. I had a similar situation and `to` worked for me.

Comment: In this simple case, this works without a doubt. But note that `\draw[->] (a) to (b) to (c);` and `\path[->] (a) edge (b) edge (c);` and `\path[->] (a) edge (b) (b) edge (c);` produce different outputs.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel what will be the difference exactly?

Comment: The first will connect `a` to `b` and `b` to `c` where the second will connect `a` to `b` as well as `a` to `c`. The third creates the first with the `edge` syntax of the second by repeating the previous target as the new start of an edge but with two arrow tips than just one. I've talked about this a bit in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662611).