# TikZ arrow tips on every subpath?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to draw a single path with relative coordinates, where every segment gets their arrow tips. I have tried

```
\draw[<->] (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0);
```

But of course, as is specified in the manual, this adds arrow tips to the first and last subpaths only, of course, so it becomes something like `<------------>`, whereas I would like it to be `<---><---><--->`.
I have read [Drawing an arrow tip to every node of a path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/drawing-an-arrow-tip-to-every-node-of-a-path) and know that an `edge` will give me arrow tips on every edge, but then I can't use incremental coordinates.
(I am actually trying to do the exact same thing that @quinmars is doing in that question.)

Since the answer to that question is 5 years old, I was hoping that either TikZ or somebody else may have an elegant solution to this?

Comment: So, are you trying to cote dimensions? (like technical drawings) if so, check this out: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14901/114143

Comment: Hmyeah that's a nice command, but I was really looking for something very simple. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For straight lines only, maybe a bit like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{arrows}{draw}{
\state{draw}[width=\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
  \path [every arrow subpath/.try] \pgfextra{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
   };
}}
\tikzset{every arrow subpath/.style={->, draw, thick}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path [decoration=arrows, decorate](0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(45:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to have arrows on both ways: not like  

`--->--->--->` but like  

`<----><----><---->`.

Comment: Just replace "->" in the .style with "<->".

Comment: It there a way to modify this so that styles declared on the `\path` are inherited? For example, so that `\path [decoration=arrows, decorate, green]` would make the path green?