# Create an implication graph in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to create a graph like the one in the image below:

[image]

Can someone please help me? I would prefer to do it using tikz if it is possible however any solution would be great.

Comment: Have you looked at for example the second tutorial in the TikZ manual (chapter 3)? While not exactly the same, if you work through that (and possibly the first tutorial), you would probably be able to do most of that yourself, and you can ask when you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks, I will look it up and ask if I get stuck. Just to be sure do you mean chapter 3 from this manual http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf?

Comment: Not exactly, that one's a bit old. Open a terminal/command prompt on your computer and type `texdoc tikz`, or get it from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quick start for you, that you can tweak.

The arrow decoration is by [Mark Wibrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/23215/mark-wibrow) from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331598/213).

```
\documentclass[border=10]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations}% for positioning nodes, decorating arrows
\pgfdeclaredecoration{arrows}{draw}{
\state{draw}[width = \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength]{%
  \path [every arrow subpath/.try] \pgfextra{%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentfirst}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}%
   };
}}
\tikzset{% define styles for each node type and edges
                 base/.style = { circle, draw },
               filled/.style = { base, fill = black!50 },
  every arrow subpath/.style = { ->, draw, thick }
}
\def\xdist{2}
\def\yheight{2.5*\xdist}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw all the nodes first
  \draw node[filled] (1)                                     {1}
        node[filled] (3) at ($(1)-(0,\yheight)$)             {3}
        node[filled] (2) at ($(1)!.5!(3)$)                   {2}
        node[base]   (9) at ($(2)+(-4*\xdist,0)$)            {9}
        node[base]   (7) at ($(9)+(\xdist,-0.6*\xdist)$)     {7}
        node[base]   (8) at ($(9)+(2*\xdist,0)$)             {8}
        node[base]   (4) at ($(8)!.5!(1)$)                   {4}
        node[base]   (6) at ($(4)-(2*\xdist,0)$)             {6}
        node[base]   (5) at ($(8)!.5!(3)$)                   {5}
  ;
  % now the fun with arrows
  \draw[decoration=arrows, decorate]
        (9) -- (8) -- (4) -- (1)
        (6) -- (8) -- (5) -- (3)
        (7) -- (8) -- (4) -- (1)
        (4) -- (2)
        (5) -- (2)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: implication graph]

Comment: This is a fantastic answer! thank you very much :)