# Arrow tips on subpath

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Is any elegant way to put arrow tips on every subpath edge?
(Yes, I have seen [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331581/tikz-arrow-tips-on-every-subpath), but, IMO, not very elegant)
It seems to me that there is a certain need for such a feature. At least it should be easier to do so.

```
\documentclass[tikz
%border=1cm
]{standalone}
   
\begin{document}
   
\begin{tikzpicture}[] 
            \pgfmathsetmacro\N{6}
            \pgfmathsetmacro\n{4*\N}
            \draw[] (0,0) 
            {
            foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
                    {
                    
                    -- ++({(2*\i-1)*90/\N}:{1-0.01*\i})
                    
                    }
            }
            ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just create separate paths (end the `edge` path operation does create its own path). Of course, you can just use the same approach with an outer `\foreach` whose body contains a full `\draw`.

The `(@)` is just a temporary coordinate (that gets redefined at every iteration).

Another option might be the `show path construction` decoration of the [`decorations.pathreplacing` library](https://tikz.dev/library-decorations#pgf.decorations.pathreplacing). Though, this will just destruct the original path and replaces it with separate paths again.
(I'm using `edge` here again so that it inherits the attributes of its parent path.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta, % better arrows (→ bounding box)
  decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} % edges
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{4*\N}
\path[->] (0,0) coordinate (@) foreach \i in {1,...,\n}{
  (@) edge coordinate[at end] (@) ++ ({(2*\i-1)*90/\N}:{1-0.01*\i})};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % separate paths
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{4*\N}
\coordinate (@) at (0,0);
\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
  \draw[->] (@) -- coordinate[at end] (@) ++ ({(2*\i-1)*90/\N}:{1-0.01*\i});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} % decoration
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{6}
\pgfmathsetmacro\n{4*\N}
\path[
  ->,
  decorate,
  decoration={
    show path construction,
    lineto code={\path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) edge (\tikzinputsegmentlast);},
  }] (0,0) foreach \i in {1,...,\n} { -- ++({(2*\i-1)*90/\N}:{1-0.01*\i}) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```