# Tikz - Draw path of arrow [Updated]

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a path of arrow like this :
[image: The goal]

I have try this code :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
        \node[circle, draw=black] (A) at (0,0){A};
        \node[circle, draw=black] (B) at (1,0){B};
        \node[circle, draw=black] (C) at (2,0){C};
        \node[circle, draw=black] (D) at (3,0){D};
        \draw[->] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But i have something like that :

[image: By the code]

How to do that ?

EDIT : I change the post

Comment: How about `\draw[->] (a) -- (b); \draw[->] (b) -- (c);`?

Comment: I have try using a \foreach, but i fing it kind of weird

Comment: You need to provide us a small compiling example that shows what you tried.  Please edit your question

Comment: For now, im in a rush, i think i do that after it (tomorow ?) mp me if i forgot

Comment: `\draw (b) edge[<-] (a) edge[->] (c);`

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331581/tikz-arrow-tips-on-every-subpath https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34943/drawing-an-arrow-tip-to-every-node-of-a-path

Comment: Or: `\draw (A) edge[->] (B) (B) edge[->] (C) (C) edge[->] (D);`

Answer (score 4):

#### Update : with the graphs library

The `graphs` library allows you to do this in a simple and concise way.
See the section `19.2.2 Concept: Chain Groups` in the pgfmanual
[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {graphs} 

\begin{document}

\tikz\graph[grow right=20mm,nodes={draw, circle,fill=cyan!30}] {A -> B -> C -> D};

\end{document}
```

#### First answer: with the chains library

The `chains` library allows you to do this. See `section 48 Chains` of the `pgfmanual`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary {chains} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=20mm, on grid,
every node/.style=draw,circle,every join/.style=->]
\begin{scope}[start chain]
\node [draw,on chain,join] {A};
\node [draw,on chain,join] {B};
\node [draw,on chain,join] {C};
\node [draw,on chain,join] {D};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to that in  @AndréC's answer (+1), but with a bit shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm, on grid,
  start chain = going right,
every node/.style = {circle, draw, on chain, join=by -{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}}
                    ]
\node {A};
\node {B};
\node {C};
\node {D};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]