# Is it possible to use marking of decoration with edge?

Tags: tikz-pgf

The initial code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\pgfkeys{
/pgf/decoration/.cd,
pre fraction/.style={pre length=#1*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength},
post fraction/.style={post length=#1*\pgfmetadecoratedpathlength}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,2);

\draw [  
decoration={ 
curveto,
pre=moveto, pre fraction=0,
post=moveto, post fraction=0.3}, decorate, red, ultra thick] (A) to[out=0,in=-90](B);

\draw [decoration={curveto,
                   pre=moveto, pre fraction=0.7,
                   post=moveto, post fraction=0},%
       decorate, blue, ultra thick,dotted] (A) to [out=0,in=-90](B); 

\path [  
decoration={ 
     markings, mark=at position .7  with {\arrow[red,line width=2pt]{>}}},  
     decorate  ] (A) to[out=0,in=-90](B);         
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

There is a problem if I want to replace `to` by `edge` . In some cases, the replacement is useful.

Is it possible to use making with edge ? and how ?

I think that the problem comes from that the `edge` operation works like a `to` operation that is added after the main path has been drawn. I get often the error that `marking` does not  work on an empty path !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I found the answer here: [texblog.net](http://texblog.net/) in the article: [Decorate a TikZ path](https://web.archive.org/web/20131102114914/http://texblog.net/latex-archive/answers/tikz/decorate-path/). (Author: Stefan Kottwitz thanks!). I do not know why I did not think earlier. There are many questions related to the use of `edge` that can be resolved like this, example: [Strange arrow mark with TikZ edge and anchors.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/strange-arrow-mark-with-tikz-edge-and-anchors)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations} 
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{every loop/.style={min distance=20mm,in=0,out=60,looseness=10}} 

   \draw (0,0) node[circle,draw]{A} edge[red,loop]  ();    
 \path[decoration={ 
     markings, mark=at position .7  with {\arrow[blue,line width=1pt]{>}}}] (0,0) node[circle]{A} edge[decorate,loop]  ();
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]