# Drawing a polyline between two nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a beginner with tikz and finding the following really difficult to do.

[image]

I have defined and drawn node1 and node2 in tikz. You can figure it out easily from the picture. What I intend to do is

- Draw a dashed line from (node1.south) to P1.
- Draw a dashed line from  P1 to P2.
- Draw a pointed dashed line from P2 to (node2.north).
- where the point P1 is (node1.south)+(0,-y). y is a positive integer which I am free to choose depending on y-axis distance between node1 and node2.
- and I define the point P2 as the point where a horizontal left-ward line from P1 meets the vertical upward line from (node2.north).
  This thing roughly accomplished in google drawing is shown.

Comment: I think you can find some hints about your questions in [High level digital design in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110209/high-level-digital-design-in-tikz).

Comment: User Qrrbrbirlbel has written a `pathortho` library that's demonstrated in [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/2552) that does exactly this kind of thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Qrrbrbirlbel's great [`paths.ortho`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/2552) library is perfect for this. Using the library, you don't have to calculate the support points manually, but instead you can simply write

```
\draw [dashed, -latex] (A) |-| (B);
```

to get

[image]

or

```
\draw [dashed, -latex, hvvh/ratio=0.7] (A) |-| (B);
```

to get

[image]

Together with Luigi's awesome [`arrows.new`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80090/2552) library, which allows you to scale arrow tips without changing the line widths or resorting to decorations, you can write

```
\draw [dashed, -latex new, arrow head=3mm, hvvh/ratio=0.7] (A) |-| (B);
```

to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho, arrows.new}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (A) {Node A};
\node [draw] (B) at (-1,-2) {Node B};
\draw [dashed, -latex new, arrow head=3mm, hvvh/ratio=0.7] (A) |-| (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, useful answer, but I had to go through the pain of figuring out how to install those packages.

Comment: Also, what does hvvh/ratio do ? and when you write "(A) |-| (B);", how does it know to start from nodeA.south to nodeB.north , as opposed to an option like nodeA.west to nodeB.north.

Comment: @dineshdileep: Sorry, I should have mentioned how to use the packages (you don't actually need to install them, it's enough to have the files in the same directory as your `.tex` file). `hvvh/ratio` determines the vertical position of the horizontal line: A value of `0.5` places it in the middle, `0` and `1` places it at the level of the endpoints. The line always starts at the edge of the node, like it would when you say `(A) -- (B)` or `(A) |- (B)` (those are standard TikZ commands).

Comment: What do you mean by edge of the node? I am sorry I have to ask this much, I am just learning tikz.

Comment: @dineshdileep: In my example, there are two nodes, `(A)` and `(B)`. When you say `\draw (A.center) -- (B.center)`, TikZ draws a line that connects the centers of the two nodes. If, however, you simply say `\draw (A) -- (B)`, without specifying a particular anchor (like `.center` or `.west`), the line will not connect the *centers* of the nodes, but their *edges*. The same thing happens in my answer. Does that clear things up a little bit? See "Connecting Nodes: Using Nodes as Coordinates" in the PGF manual for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: what do you mean by edges? are A.south and A.west edges or anchors? that is what I didn't understand.

Comment: @dineshdileep: Sorry, maybe "edge" isn't the right word: I mean the border of the node (the rectangles around the words "Node A" and "Node B", in this case). `A.south` is an anchor, in this case a particular point on the border of the node.

Comment: Thus, as I understand, A.south and A.west both lie on the border of the node, why didn't tikz select A.west? Is it kind of a shortest distance rule?

Comment: @dineshdileep: It's determined by the *direction* of the line: In the case of `\draw (A) -- (B)`, TikZ will use the point on the border of node `A` in the direction of node `B`. If you use `\draw (A) |- (B)`, it will use either `A.north` or `A.south` (depending on whether node `B` is above or below node `A`).

Answer (score 19):

General points can be computed using the `calc` library of `tikz`.  An expression of the form

```
($x!t!y$)
```

will find the point a fraction `t` along the line from `x` to `y`.  Combining this with drawing directives `|-` and `-|` for "vertical then horizontal" and vice versa gives:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[rectangle,fill=blue!30,draw] (A) at (6,4) {Node 1};
  \node[rectangle,fill=blue!30,draw] (B) at (0,0) {Node 2};
  \draw[dashed,->] (A.south) |- ($(A)!.7!(B)$) -| (B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

There are different ways to change the arrow.  Firstly, just writing

```
\draw[dashed,->,>=stealth]
```

will give another shape.  Loading the `tikz` library `arrows` gives plenty to choose between.  Making the line thicker will also make the arrow more prominent, e.g. the combination

```
\draw[dashed,->,>=stealth,very thick]
```

[image: Sample stealth arrow]

Note that you could start your picture with `\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,very thick]` to make all arrowheads of `stealth` type, and all lines `very thick`.

For more control over the arrow, you can use the `decorations` mechanism.  In your case this could look like:

[image: Sample decoration]

from the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with
  {\arrow[scale=3]{>}}}]
  \node[rectangle,fill=blue!30,draw] (A) at (6,4) {Node 1};
  \node[rectangle,fill=blue!30,draw] (B) at (0,0) {Node 2};
  \draw[dashed,postaction={decorate}] 
  (A.south) |- ($(A)!.7!(B)$) -| (B.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

See the [`pgf` manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for further details and constructions.  Another illustration of arrow tips via decorations may be found at [TikZ: Large arrow tips at the end of smooth curves](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46853/15925).

Comment: +1, nice!, also can you please tell me how to make the arrow head more pronounced and thick.

Comment: Usefull answer and your help is appreciated, I really wish I could accept your answer along with the other one.