# What's the difference between \path and \draw in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-core

The question is in the title: What is the difference between the commands `\path` and `\draw` in Tikz? The [PGF and TikZ manual by Till Tantau](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf) tells me (on page 26 of the current version) that “`\draw` is just a shorthand for `\path[draw]`”.

In some of the answers I got to previous questions on how to draw certain figures using `Tikz`, some users have used a mixture of `\path` and`\draw` in their code, while others only seemed to use `\draw`.

The [very helpful slides](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/TikZ.pdf) Marc van Dongen has on his website explaining the basic features of Tikz also contain a mixture of both, whilst mostly relying on the `\draw` command.

To remedy this confusion, I have as of now switched to using exclusivley `\draw`, but I find it very confusing.

What is the difference between the two commands? Should I be using both? When is it better to use `\path` instead of `\draw` and vice versa? When is it all the same? Are there things `\path` can do that `\draw` cannot?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Sometimes we only need a virtual path, or a totally transparent path just to compute some coordinates, intersections, and so on.

To do an invisible path we use `\path` and if you want to put some ink on it you use `\draw`.

**Example:** Here is an example where I used some paths to compute the intersections.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]\footnotesize 
\clip (-1.2,-.3) rectangle (4,1.75);
\begin{scope}[rotate=70]
\coordinate (q) at (0,0);
%
\draw[dashed] (q) circle (1);
\draw[dotted](0,-.8)--(0,.8)node[left=1.5em]{$\mathcal{K}$};
%
\path[name path=ray1] (q)-- (35:3cm);
\path[name path=ray2] (q)-- (0:3cm);
\path[name path=ray3] (q)-- (-40:3cm);
\path[name path=ray4] (q)-- (-60:3.5cm);
\path[name path=ray5] (q)-- (-70:4cm);
\draw[name path=circulo] (q)+(.4,0) circle (.4);
\draw[name path=vertical] (1.25,-4)node[above left=10pt]{$L$} -- (1.25,2);
%
\draw[name intersections={of=ray1 and vertical,by={b}}]  (q)--(b);
\draw[name intersections={of=ray2 and vertical,by={a}}]  (q)--(a);
\draw[dotted,name intersections={of=ray3 and vertical,by={v3}}]  (q)--(v3);
\draw[dotted,name intersections={of=ray4 and vertical,by={v4}}]  (q)--(v4);
\draw[dotted,name intersections={of=ray5 and vertical,by={v5}}]  (q)--(v5);
%
\path[name intersections={of=ray1 and circulo,by={btilde}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=ray2 and circulo,by={atilde}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=ray3 and circulo,by={c31,c32}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=ray4 and circulo,by={c41,c42}}] ;
\path[name intersections={of=ray5 and circulo,by={c51,c52}}] ;
%
\draw (atilde)--(btilde);
\draw[rotate=35] (btilde) rectangle +(-.07,-.07);
\draw[rotate=0] (a) rectangle +(-.07,.07);
\foreach \p in {q,btilde,atilde,c32,c42,c52,b,a,v3,v4,v5}{
\draw[fill=white] (\p) circle (.7pt); }
%
\node[left=2pt] at (btilde){$\tilde b$};
\node[right=2pt] at (atilde){$\tilde a$};
\node[above=2pt] at (a){$a$};
\node[above=2pt] at (b){$b$};
\node[below=2pt] at (q){$q$};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an example of this? What to do with an invisible path?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat You can place coordinate/nodes on a path, or to be precise: along a sub-path (with the `pos` key and its family). As a matter of fact: `\node` expands to `\path node` (although, in most case `\draw node` will work, too). If you only want to fill a path, you use `\fill` (expands to `\path[fill]`). Here you you want a `draw` neither. Another thing: If you use `edge`s, you should use `\path` instead of `\draw` because [strange things will happen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15567/16595); the `edge` operator creates separate paths anyway, and we use `\path` only for the parser.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat, I'd edited.

Comment: Beautiful answer! An invisible path is also useful for clipping, I use it a lot for that. :)

Comment: Thanks, this code is quite illuminating. I don't understand the `c31,c23` stuff though, what is going on there?

Comment: They are the intersection points of those 3 no labeled dotted lines with the small circle.

Comment: Yes, but why was it necessary to give the two intersections a name, but only one name for the two intersections of, say, `ray1` with `circulo`? I guess `name intersections` labels intersections from top to bottom?

Comment: If I remember, I need the second intersection point so I need to save both. For example, remove `c31` and keep `c32`. Then note that the small bullet there will be removed also since the `c32` will refer to the first point, that is, `q`.

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate half-lines in tikz? This would be useful for calculations.