# How to draw Automata/graph

Tags: graphs, automata

I'm new to LaTeX. How can I make this automaton?[image]

Comment: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/nodetutorial/ might serve as a starting point

Comment: https://www3.nd.edu/~kogge/courses/cse30151-fa17/Public/other/tikz_tutorial.pdf ; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbiwHzjPUmw ; https://hayesall.com/blog/latex-automata/ ; https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/automata-and-petri-nets/ from search term: tikz automata // see also links to the right, like: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20784/which-package-can-be-used-to-draw-automata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using plain `tikz`:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm]
        % position the nodes a..d
        \node (a) [] {$\textrm{I}$};
        \node (b) [right of=a] {};
        \node (c) [right of=b] {};
        \node (d) [right of=c] {};
        
        % draw the bullets/circles at the above defined positions
        \draw (b) circle (5pt);
        \filldraw (b) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \filldraw (c) circle (1.5pt);
        
        \draw (d) circle (5pt);
        \filldraw (d) circle (1.5pt);
        
        % draw arrows/connections, use 'shorten' to finetune space
        \draw[->, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=-2pt] (a) -- (b) ; 
        \draw[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt] (b) -- (c) 
            node [above=0pt, pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$};
        
        \path[->, shorten >=3pt, shorten <=1pt, bend left] 
            (c) edge node [above=0., pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$0$} (d) ;
        \path[->, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=3pt, bend left] 
            (d) edge node [below=0., pos=0.5, font=\footnotesize]{$\varepsilon$} (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

I guess the code should be relatively clear. In case of doubt I can also add some comments and explanations.
**update**: just added a few comments.

Comment: What is the difference between \path and \draw ?

Comment: I'll reply with a link to a highly decorated answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/whats-the-difference-between-path-and-draw-in-tikz In my code, the first \path[draw... can actually replaced by \draw (roughly speaking, a path is invisible until drawn, the draw command is already visible). Does my code answer your original question?

Comment: Answered. Thank you. But I still don't understand the difference between \path and \draw. To me they seem to be the same thing.

Comment: The main difference is: If you don't want to draw the "connections" then you only use path. If you want to draw the connections then you use \draw or \path[draw]. Also, please mark my answer/code above as correct if this solved your problem, thanks!