# Drawing arrows using tikz library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to implement a visual representation of linked list using tikz library.

The code written so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{box}=[draw, fill=pink!10, text centered]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0cm,outer sep = 0pt]
    \node (A) [box,minimum height=7mm, minimum width=7mm] {\textbf{12}};
    \node (B) [box,anchor=west,minimum height=7mm, minimum width=7mm] at (A.east) {\textbf{\textbullet}};

    \node (C) [box, anchor=west, minimum height=7mm, minimum width=7mm] at ([xshift=10mm]B.east) {\textbf{98}};
    \node (D) [box,anchor=west,minimum height=7mm, minimum width=7mm] at (C.east) {\textbf{\textbullet}};

    \draw[thick,->] (B.center) edge [bend left=0]  node {} (C);

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Things are looking good except the arrow getting out from node B (first bullet) has also a tip. How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Do not use `\draw` with `edge`. Use *always* `\path`: [Strange arrow mark with TikZ edge and anchors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15567/16595) Also, the `arrows` library is deprecated since TikZ/PGF 3.0. Look up the `arrows.meta` library.