# Can't seem to make an arrow on one side of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to make a very simple arrow with Tikz, like this: `--->`
But I only seem to get arrows that like `<--->` and `----><`.
I'm very new to LaTex and Tikz, so I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what it is. This is my code:

```
\coordinate (v2) at (3.5,6.5) {};
\draw[->, line width=1mm]  (v2) edge node[near start, auto, scale=2] {$F$} (3.5,4);
```

This is the result:

[image]

I also tried: `<-`, which gives me the only one arrow, but to the wrong side, so I tried to swap the two points, but that gives me the following result. Notice that the second arrow looks different:

[image]

for reference, this is the code for the second image:

```
\coordinate (v2) at (3.5,6.5) {};
\draw[<-, line width=1mm]  (3.5,4) edge node[near start, auto, scale=2] {$F$} (v2);
```

I also tried to make the arrow with `|->` but that just renders the `|` in the second arrow

I used TikzEdt to draw the image and finetuned later in the document in TexStudio, both use pdflatex.

Comment: Did you use some `\tikzset` or `\tikzstyle` command that you didn't show us?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15567/strange-arrow-mark-with-tikz-edge-and-anchors

Answer (score 0):

compare code below with your and observe difference:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[->, line width=1mm]  (0,0) edge node[near start, auto, scale=2] {$F$} (0,3);
\draw[->, line width=1mm]  (2,0)  --  node[near start, auto, scale=2] {$F$} (2,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]