# Why do we get (undesired) arrow head at start of arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I tried drawing an arrow between two nodes, and wanted to use the `east` anchor and found a strange behaviour: If you add that anchor it seems you get an additional arrow head pointing in some strange direction, but I couldn't find any explanation on why you should get this. Can anyone elaborate why we do get this additional arrow head and how one would go about removing it?

I tried demonstrating this effect with a minimal example: The arrow between `a` and `b` has a head at `a` (which I was referring to above). I expected that this arrow should have no arrow head there and should look exactly like the arrow between `c` and `d`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[circle, draw] (b) at (1,0) {b};
\draw[->] (a.east) edge (b);
\node[circle, draw] (c) at (0,-1) {c};
\node[circle, draw] (d) at (1,-1) {d};
\draw[->] (c) edge (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here the corresponding screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: No idea. If you replace `edge` by `--` or `to` the left arrow disappear.

Comment: `\draw (a.east) edge[->] (b);` You find the explanation here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15587/231952.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks that seems to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw] (a) at (0,0) {a};
\node[circle, draw] (b) at (1,0) {b};
\draw[->] (a.east) to (b);
\node[circle, draw] (c) at (0,-1) {c};
\node[circle, draw] (d) at (1,-1) {d};
\draw[->] (c) to (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The question was not how to remove the arrow, but *why* does it appear in the first place.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. While replacing `edge` with `to` is a workaround in this case, they do not behave the same everywhere.