# Display weight without edge with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, transparency, edge

I would like to put a weight on an invisible edge in a graph.
I tried to use opacity to make the edge disapear and let the weight, but obviously the weight is affected to.

Do you have a solution ?
Thank you !

Below, an example of what I have, and what I want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,shapes,automata,decorations,shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
          auto,
          mynode/.style={ellipse, draw, 
            inner sep=0.4mm, minimum size=7mm, font=\scriptsize,
            node distance=6mm and 4mm},
          void/.style={ellipse, minimum size=7mm, node distance=6mm and 4mm},
          myarc/.style={thick, ->,>=triangle 45, font=\scriptsize}]
    
          \node[mynode] (asia) {asia};
          \node[mynode, below= of asia] (tub) {tub};
         
          \draw[myarc, opacity=0] (asia) edge node{2} (tub);

        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Edge and weight is invisible]

[image: Edge is invisible but weight is visible.]

Comment: Welcome! @Qrrbrbirlbel has given you the solution, but just a comment... your code is not exactly a *minimal* example, is it? You could have reduced the tikz to just one-line, making life much easier for people willing to help... 

Comment: @Rmano, I reduced my example, thank you.

@Qrrbrbirlbel, thanks for your answer. I tried ```\draw[draw=none]``` and ```\draw[myarc, draw=none]```, but the edge doesn't disappear. I don't know how to use ```move to```, I didn't find any entry in the tikzpgf Manual.

Comment: There is `\path (either) -- (xray) node[myarc, midway]{2};`  See also `[pos=0.5]`.

Comment: ```\draw[myarc, opacity=0] (asia) edge node[opacity=1]{2} (tub);``` works very well, thank you @John Kormylo !

Comment: Oops, I deleted the edge node comment.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of ways to draw a line in TikZ, there are also dozens of ways to not draw a line. Using `opacity = 0` (and `text opacity=1` or `opacity = 1` for the node to reactivate it for the node) is one but I don't think it is the proper way to not draw a line here.

---

The `edge` operation is a special operation in TikZ because it creates an extra `\path` after the one it is used one (which is usually otherwise empty). It is best to be used to connect nodes (hence the name).

Two things are a bit different:

1. A new edge will start at the previous start position. This means

   ```
   \path (a) edge (b)
             edge (c)
             edge (d);
   ```

   will connect `a` to `b`, `a` to `c` and `a` to `d` (and not `b` to `c` and `c` to `d`).
2. It uses the `every edge` style that is initialized by TikZ with `draw`. (Because we usually want to connect two nodes by a line if we want to visualize a connection between them.)

The latter is the reason why an `edge` will be drawn even if you say

```
\path [draw=none] (a) edge (b);
```

This `draw=none` (which is usually not needed because unless the `every path` style is changed `\path` will not draw something) will be passed down to the edge (as will `->` in `\path[->] (a) edge (b);`)
but it will be overruled by the `every edge` style.

This is why you will need

```
\path[myarc] (either) edge[draw=none] node {2} (xray);
```

to not draw that edge or

```
\path[myarc, every edge/.style=] (either) edge node {2} (xray);
```

to reset `every edge` to an empty style.

If you need this often, I'd suggest defining an alias for those by adding

```
\tikzset{
  no edges/.style={every edge/.style=},
  no edge/.style ={draw=none}
}
```

to your preamble, then you can just say

```
\path[myarc]           (either) edge[no edge] node {2} (xray);
% or
\path[myarc, no edges] (either) edge          node {2} (xray);
```

Of course, if you only need one edge to not be drawn you could use the edge-less version by doing

```
\path (either) -- node {2} (xray);
```

which will usually not draw a line.

(With the `calc` library, there's also `($(either)!.5!(xray)$)` which will calculate the halfway between the nodes' center – whereas the node placed along a line will be placed halfway between the nodes' borders. You also lose the ability of `auto`matic placement and the `sloped` functionality.)

---

I've taken the liberty to place your nodes with a `\matrix` and the [`matrix of nodes` style](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix#tikz/matrix:of:nodes) which makes it very easy to place the nodes in a grid like manner without auxilliary nodes or overlapping of the nodes. The `matrix of nodes` settings allows us to give any options that would be allowed between `\node` and `{<text of node>}` to be placed between two `|` at the start of a cell.

I've used `edge`to its full effect. I've also added a `no edge` style (which is just a speaking name for `draw=none`) that also includes `auto=false` so that the `2` will placed more between the nodes and not besides an non-existing line.

---

There's also the [`tikz-cd` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) which could have been used here (it uses a `\matrix` internally) even though your diagram is not commutative.

The [`graphs` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs) can also make life easier when connection a bunch of nodes but one needs to learn a new but shorter syntax.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, shapes.geometric, matrix}
\tikzset{
  no edges/.style={every edge/.style=},
  no edge/.style ={draw=none, auto=false}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  auto,
  mynode/.style= {ellipse, draw, bottom color = red!5, top color = orange!15,
    black, text = black, inner sep=0.4mm, minimum size=7mm, font=\scriptsize},
  myedge/.style= {thick, -,              font=\scriptsize},
  myarc/.style = {thick, ->, >=Triangle, font=\scriptsize}]

\matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes=mynode, row sep=6mm, column sep=3mm] {
  |(asia)| asia  &                   &                & |(smoke)| smoke \\
  |(tub)|  tub   &                   & |(lung)| lung                    \\
                 & |(either)| either &                & |(bronc)| bronc \\
  |(xray)| x-ray &                   & |(dysp)| dysp                    \\
};

\path[myedge] (tub) edge        node {1} (asia)
                    edge        node {1} (xray)
                    edge[myarc] node {0} (either);
\path[myarc] (either) edge          node {2} (lung)
                      edge          node {0} (dysp)
                      edge[no edge] node {2} (xray)
              (smoke) edge          node {0} (bronc)
                      edge          node {0} (lung)
              (lung)  edge          node {2} (bronc)
              (bronc) edge          node {0} (dysp);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I never use TikZ's `edge` operation, and feel good ^^

In fact, TikZ has only one main command `\path`; if one really wants to draw, then apply it to the path option `\path[draw]` or shortly `\draw`; if one doesn't want to draw ("*to make the edge disapear*" in OP's words), then just ... do nothing, just `\path`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[nodes={ellipse,draw,minimum size=7mm}] 
(0,0)     node (asia) {asia}
+(0,-1.5) node (tub) {tub}
+(2.5,0)  node (africa) {africa}
+(-2.5,0) node (europe) {europe}
;
\path 
(asia)--(tub)    node[midway,right]{2}
(asia)--(africa) node[midway,above]{3}
(asia)--(europe) node[midway,below]{4}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```