# Double line with TikZ "quotes" library

Tags: tikz-pgf

While using the TikZ `quotes` library to put labels on lines, the `double` option of `\draw` does not seem to work.
Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (1,2) {A};
\node (B) at (3,4) {B};

\draw [double] (A) edge["Label"] (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output does not have a double line.]

How do I make the double line appear?

Comment: It doesn't work without the `quotes` library either. If you want to use it on more than one edge on one path use `\path[every edge/.append style=double] (A) edge["Label"] (B) (B) edge["Another Label"] (A);`. [Edges are special.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/662611)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `double` property on the edge instead:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (A) at (1,2) {A};
\node (B) at (3,4) {B};

\draw (A) edge[double,"Label"] (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]